# Image Upload onClick does not open the image gallery window

Tags: javascript, file-upload

Upon clicking the image icon, it should open the image gallery. However, in this case it does not work. The interesting thing is the exact implementation works on another page. Below is a component which I then call to a page. The implementation that works is a component called to a separate page also. I cannot see any fundamental difference that would account for an error. No error pertaining to this is logged either. Does anyone know what could possibly be wrong by looking at this? Or is able to point me in the right direction for troubleshooting?

```
    export default function Step1AddItems() {
    
    const [image, setImage] = useState({ preview: "", raw: "" });
    
    const handleItemChange = e => {
       if (e.target.files.length) {
          setImage({
            preview: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]),
            raw: e.target.files[0]
          });
        }
      };

    const handleItemUpload = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("image", image.raw);

        await fetch("", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
          },
          body: formData
        });
      }; 
    
      // if(props.currentStep !== 1) {
      //   return null;
      // }
```

//Markup for step 1 UI

````
    return(
            
        <Row>
        <Col size="md-6" fixed>
    
        <div>  
        <label htmlFor="item-upload-button">
          {image.preview ? (
            <img src={image.preview} alt="dummy" width="300" height="300" />
          ) : (
            <img src={require("../../images/store.jpg")} style={{justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}} alt="placeholder" width="100" height="100" />
            // <>
            //   <span className="fa-stack fa-2x mt-3 mb-2">
            //     <i className="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x" />
            //     <i className="fas fa-store fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" />
            //   </span>
            //   {/* <h5 className="text-center">Upload your photo</h5> */}
            // </>
          )}
        </label>
               <input 
               type="file" 
               id="upload-button"
               style={{ display: "none" }} 
               onChange={handleItemChange} />
               <br/>
               <button onClick={handleItemUpload}>Upload</button>
              </div>       
    
          <div>
          <label htmlFor="item-upload-button">
          {image.preview ? (
            <img src={image.preview} alt="dummy" width="300" height="300" />
          ) : (
            <img src={require("../../images/store.jpg")} style={{justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}} alt="placeholder" width="100" height="100" />
            // <>
            //   <span className="fa-stack fa-2x mt-3 mb-2">
            //     <i className="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x" />
            //     <i className="fas fa-store fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" />
            //   </span>
            //   {/* <h5 className="text-center">Upload your photo</h5> */}
            // </>
          )}
        </label>
               <input 
               type="file" 
               id="upload-button" 
               style={{ display: "none" }} 
               onChange={handleItemChange} />
               <br />
               <button onClick={handleItemUpload}>Upload</button>
               </div>
               <br />
    
          <div>
         <label htmlFor="item-upload-button">
          {image.preview ? (
            <img src={image.preview} alt="dummy" width="300" height="300" />
          ) : (
            <img src={require("../../images/store.jpg")} style={{justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}} alt="placeholder" width="100" height="100" />
            // <>
            //   <span className="fa-stack fa-2x mt-3 mb-2">
            //     <i className="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x" />
            //     <i className="fas fa-store fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" />
            //   </span>
            //   {/* <h5 className="text-center">Upload your photo</h5> */}
            // </>
          )}
        </label>
               <input type="file" 
               id="upload-button" 
               style={{ display: "none" }} 
               onChange={handleItemChange} /> 
               <br />
               <button onClick={handleItemUpload}>Upload</button>
               </div>
                
      
          <div>
          <label htmlFor="item-upload-button">
          {image.preview ? (
            <img src={image.preview} alt="dummy" width="300" height="300" />
          ) : (
            <img src={require("../../images/store.jpg")} style={{justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}} alt="placeholder" width="100" height="100" />
            // <>
            //   <span className="fa-stack fa-2x mt-3 mb-2">
            //     <i className="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x" />
            //     <i className="fas fa-store fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" />
            //   </span>
            //   {/* <h5 className="text-center">Upload your photo</h5> */}
            // </>
          )}
        </label>
               <input 
               type="file" 
               id="upload-button" 
               style={{ display: "none" }} 
               onChange={handleItemChange} />
               <br />
               <button onClick={handleItemUpload}>Upload</button>
               </div>
               
              </Col>
              </Row>

)}```
````

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo - I changed <label htmlFor=**"item-upload-button"**> to <label htmlFor=**"upload-button"**> and it worked - the image gallery window opened up.